# Determine if PIN is set on Windows Phone 8/8.1 and lock the WP8/8.1 phone through code

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I was wondering if there are any documented/undocumented API's for:
1. Determining if the device has a PIN password set, and 
2. Locking the screen through code.

Thanks!
/Loren

Answer (score 0):

There is not any API for checking PIN password set or not and locking the phone by app code so there is very thin possibility to finding any documentation regarding that